# How do I call the current user who posses a subdomain using django tenant?

Tags: python, django

I am using [django tenant](https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for a saas application. Following the model configuration below, how do I call the present user who owns the current subdomain?

```
class Client(TenantMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    paid_until = models.DateField(default=ten_days)
    on_trial = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='clients', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Domain(DomainMixin):
    pass
```

DomainMixin config is as follows in the package:

```
class DomainMixin(models.Model):
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=253, unique=True, db_index=True)
    tenant = models.ForeignKey(settings.TENANT_MODEL, db_index=True, related_name='domains',
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # Set this domain to true if this is the primary domain
    is_primary = models.BooleanField(default=True, db_index=True)
```

`settings.TENANT_MODEL` is pointing to Client, I tried as follows:

```
current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
try:
    current_domain = current_site.domain
    domain_active = Domain.objects.get(domain=current_domain)
    user = domain_active.tenant.user
    print(user)
except:
    pass
```

However, I am not getting the output on terminal, somebody could show me the right way?

Comment: Is that *sass* or *SaaS* application?

Comment: its my mistake, its a saas application